# How to convert simple_html_dom object back to string?

Tags: php, dom, moodle, simple-html-dom, gettype

I have used [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to first convert an HTML string to DOM object by `str_get_html()` method of simple_html_dom.php

```
$summary = str_get_html($html_string);
```

1. Then I extracted an `<img>` object from the `$summary` by

   ```
   foreach ($summary->find('img') as $img) {
       $image = $img;
       break;
   }
   ```

   Now I needed to convert $image DOM object back to a string. I used
   the [Object Oriented way mentioned here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#container_dump):

   ```
   $image_string = $image->save();
   ```

   **I got the error (from the *Moodle debugger*):**

   > Fatal error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom_node::save() ...
2. So I thought since I am working with Moodle, it may have something
   to do with Moodle, so I simply did the simple (non-object oriented?)
   way [from the same manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

   ```
   $image_string = $image;
   ```

   Then just to check/confirm that it has been converted to a string, I
   did:

   ```
   echo '$image TYPE: '.gettype($image);
   echo '<br><br>';
   echo '$image_string TYPE: '.gettype($image_string);
   ```

   **But this prints:**

   ```
   $image TYPE: object

   $image_string TYPE: object
   ```

**So the question is Why??? Am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just cast it to a string in the normal way:

```
$image_string = (string)$image
```

Comment: Oh this is great. I didn't try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use outertext

```
$image_string = $image->outertext();
```

I looked in the code. function save return

```
$ret = $this->root->innertext();
```

But this is method of class `simple_html_dom`. After searching you receive object `simple_html_dom_node`. It hasn't such method and does not inherit. But has `text`, `innertext` and `outertext`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a good "hack", right? DO you have any idea why don't the methods described in the manual work?

Comment: It's from docs :)  I use only such way and don't know about save :)

Comment: [Here!](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) See the section titled 'How to dump contents of DOM object?' and click the _tabs_ titled 'Quick way' and 'Object-oriented way'.

Comment: I am wrong. `Save` must work but return full tree, not the object. So why i never used it :)

Answer (score 1):

$image->text();
this worked for me

Comment: I can't find the `text()` function in the [API reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Comment: yup this is not in the api reference but when you var_dum($image) you will see this method